# MitmProxy Transparent Proxy + Wireshark - Decrypting TLS 1.3 Traffic

Tags: wireshark, tls1.2, mitmproxy, transparentproxy, tls1.3

I have a setup as follows to inspect traffic from a device.

`Device <---> MitmProxy (Transparent Proxy mode) + Wireshark <---> Internet`

Command used to invoke MitmProxy: `SSLKEYLOGFILE="$PWD/mitmproxy/sslkeylogfile.txt" mitmweb --mode transparent --showhost`

MitmProxy supports logging SSL/TLS master keys which allows Wireshark to decrypt the corresponding TLS traffic.

However, I noticed that the contents of my `SSLKEYLOGFILE` contained only lines of `CLIENT_RANDOM` which decrypts TLS 1.2 traffic.

To decrypt TLS 1.3 traffic, I understand that 4 `secrets` - `CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET` and `SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET` are needed, all of which are absent from my `SSLKEYLOGFILE`.

How may I proceed with decrypting TLS 1.3 in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently is a known bug in mitmproxy, see https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3994. We're waiting for upstream to expose the new OpenSSL hooks.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me, I thought I had the setup done incorrectly. Awaiting for changes from upstream. :)